# Display data from database into Phonegap app using Onsen-ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap-build, onsen-ui

I am using Onsen-Ui to develop an app. I use Websql Database to store some list and want to show in a page.
But after data are retrieved, not display. But when I click some button on Navigation bar, the whole list view appears. Here is js code.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {

    loadingViewOne.show();
    $scope.isEditing = false;
    $scope.myChecked = false;
    $scope.downloadedLists = [];
    this.store = new WebSqlStore(function() {
    });
    //alert('webstore start');
    this.store.retrieveAll(function(allPublications){
        //alert('webstore finished');
        $scope.downloadedLists = allPublications; // allPublications is data from DB
        $scope.$apply //------------------This is the answer...
        $scope.finishedRetrieving = true;
        loadingViewOne.hide();
        //appendListView(allPublications);
    });

}
```

Here is HTML code..

```
<ons-list ng-show="finishedRetrieving"><!-- List Item -->
<ons-list-item ng-repeat="rows in downloadedLists">
    <br><!--Space between Rows-->
    <ons-row>
        <ons-col width="33.33%" ng-repeat="list in rows"><!-- Column Grid Item-->

            <button class="button button--quiet" style="width: 100%" ng-click="downloadNav.pushPage('readingView.html', {issueNo: list})" ng-disabled="isEditing">
                <img src="services/pics/{{list.pic}}" width="100%" height = "100%" />
            </button>

            <p style="text-align: center; width: 95%;">{{list.firstName}}</p>
        </ons-col>

    </ons-row>
</ons-list-item>
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: have you tried with `$scope.$apply();` after you retrieve the data?

Comment: You answer works perfectly, Andi Pavllo. Please write as an answer. Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `$scope.$apply();`, which updates bidings.

You can find more about it [here](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html)